# DotEnv doesn't get .env params

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, dotenv

I'm trying to create an independent module in `nestjs` for database connections, the problem is that the actual configuration doesn't get params values.

The actual `database.module` file:

```
import {Module} from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

@Module({

  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath:".env",
      isGlobal:true}),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type:'mysql',
      host:process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
      port:parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
      username:process.env.DATABASE_USER,
      password:process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
      database:process.env.DATABASE,
      synchronize:true,
      entities:[__dirname+"../../domain/entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}"]
    }),
  ],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule]
})
export class DatabaseModule{}
```

database.module.ts is located in `src/infrastructure/database` directory, and in the same directory exists the `.env` file with credentials associated to variables described into `DatabaseModule`

The `app.module.ts` file contains:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DatabaseModule } from './infrastructure/database/database.module';
import { UserModule } from './infrastructure/modules/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    UserModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    DatabaseModule,
  ],
  exports:[]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Did you install `dotenv`? And need to include `require('dotenv').config()`

Comment: Don't you get all the config or process.env variables?

Comment: None of the variables are being getted

Comment: @DreamBold you mean to `import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';` and in each TypeORM parameter user `require('dotenv).config()` or something alike ?

Comment: How do you import `database.module` in the main js/ts file?

Comment: Into imports section ??, @DreamBold I'm goint to add  `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this way:

```
@Module({
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: `${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env` }),
MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@myhost.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority&db=dbname`, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'dbname' })
...
})
```

as you already have used import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
Instead of these in your code

```
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot({
envFilePath:".env",
isGlobal:true}),
```

So the final would be:

```
imports: [
ConfigModule.forRoot({
envFilePath:`${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
isGlobal:true}),
.... TypeOrm Module (...
```

Then try to setting the script in your `package.json` file this way:

```
"scripts": {
"start: local": "NODE_ENV=local npm run start"
"start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev npm run start"
}
```

Hope it helps!